# Is there a way to input multiple numbers in a function, but when 0 is inputted the script starts

Tags: python, math, average

I am trying to make a script that will let you input numbers, until 0 is inputted then it will calculate the aritmetic mean or average of numbers that have been inputted except 0.
This is what I have so far:

```
a=int(input())
b=0
d=0
while a!=0:
    c=int(input())
    d+=1
    if c !=0:
        break
b=a+c
average=b/c

print(average)
```

The problem with this one is that it only lets me input 2 values. 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please explain `if c !=0: break`.

Comment: ...and what is d for? It just goes up by one each loop and is never used (you could use it to solve your problem though). Did you write this or is this some kind of 'spot the deliberate mistakes' exam question?

Comment: My thinking here was that I will input a (that is not 0) it will see that it isn't, it will go into a while function which will repeat itself with giving me inputs of c and if c==0 then it will stop, that's what if c!=0 break is for

Comment: d measures the length of inputs being made, so i can calculate the average. Sum / length (not an exam question, but homework :^)

Comment: `b=0
d=0
c=0
while b==0:
    a=float(input())
    if a>b or a<b:
        d+=1
        c=a+a
    else:
        break
mean=c/d
print(mean)`   Thank you mates for your inputs once again, this is my finished product @ScottHunter @SimonN

Comment: Note that `if c!=0: break` means *if c is NOT 0 then stop (`break`) the loop*.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something simpler?

```
a=float(input()) # enter the first input value, it can be also zero
avr=0
t=0 # enter the counter to measure the number of entries
while(a!=0): # you will stop if "a" is a zero
    # if you are here "a" is not zero, so we
    # can add it to the cumulative sum
    avr+=a
    t+=1 # increase the counter
    # re enter the input, if zero the loop will stop without
    # at the next iteration without changing the cumulative sum or the counter
    a=float(input())

# now to avoid division by zero (in case you entered zero as first value), we
# need an if to print out the results
if(t>0):
  print("mean value{}".format(avr/t))
```

Comment: I only know bare bones of this program so your way of doing it is kind of apstract to me, thanks for helping anyways

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste the code and run it?
There are several comments in what I wrote, they should be easy enough to follow.

Comment: Yes I have tried, but I think you needed to implement avr=0 before, helpful nonetheless

Comment: Yep, you are totally right!  I made a mistake!  I am correcting the answer.  In one of the first edit "avr" was there.  I wonder why I removed it.